# gettin error importing from parent to child or from sibling in python package ;

Tags: python

I have a structure like this

```py
project/ 
       __init__.py 
       main.py ==> class test 
       pack_1 /
               mod_1.py. ==> func_1 
               __init__.py 
       pack_2 / 
       mod_2.py ==> func_2 
       __init__.py
```

```py
#main.py
from pack_2.mod_2 import func_2
class test:
      pass

#mod_1.py
from main import test 
from pack_2.mod2 import func_2
def func_1():
    pass

#mod_2.py 

def func_2():
    pass
```

1- I have already added the project directory to path variables using sys.path.append(os.getcwd()). I can see the path is added when I run sys.path , but in my terminal I dont see it when I run echo $PATH ?

2- Also , when I run mod_1.py or mod_2.py in pycharm they run just fine , but I am facing ModuleNotFoundError when I run them in Terminal (for instance : python pack_1/mod_1.py)

3- do I need to have **init**.py in the root directory (project beside main.py)

I am new to packaging and modular coding in python and I really appreciate if someone can clear up those confusions.

Comment: This looks like **circular dependency problem**, since you are `importing mod1 in main` and also `importint main in mod1`, Can you share error log?

Comment: yes , you are right , I have just took care of it . I will edit my question . But still I have the same problem . everything is working fine in my PyCharm IDE . Even main.py works fine in my terminal (python main.py) but mod1.py and mod2.py don't work in my terminal .  I guess soemthing shoudl be wrong with my PYTHONPATH or sys.path ; I really dont understand the difference between these two , since when I run sys.path it gives me something different than echo $PATH (terminal) . <br/>

Comment: `(venv) (base) hamedniakan@Hameds-MacBook-Pro project_test % python pack_1/mod_1.py `
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pack_1/mod_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pack_2.mod_2 import fun_2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pack_2' `